# How to make the click on a search button filter the list of items in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React.js. How do I make the search button list out the items in a list.Right now its doing nothing

`<Button type = 'submit'>Search</Button>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onClick` param for this, add it to the button then give it whatever function you want to run:

```js
<button onClick={listItems}>Search</button>
```

Or

```js
<button onClick={() => listItems()}>Search</button>
```

Or

```js
<button onClick={() => {
    console.log(listOfItems)
}}>Search</button>
```

Comment: From the console logs i see the list of items, but how do i get the items to filter if i select one item and it shows on my page? The closest i have seen on youtube is this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RM_nXOyHwN0

Comment: Have a look at the array methods in the mdn docs. You'll either want to use `listOfItems.find` or `listOfItems.findIndex`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex